# Why getAttribute('ng-reflect-model ') returns Null in my case?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to compare my tag ng-reflect-model, but protractor is return me null. Why?

**My HTML Code:**

```
**Input Tag code**:


  <input class="form-control ng-datepicker-input ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty" maxlength="10" name="viewValue" oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false" onkeypress="return event.charCode > = 48 &amp;&amp; event.charCode <= 57" type="text" ng-reflect-name="viewValue" ng-reflect-model="12/03/4567">
```

**My Test Code:**

```
it('Deve verificar se o campo de Fim Vigência só aceita numeros', function()    
      {
      var fimVigencia = element(by.xpath('/html/body/application/auth-
                container/layout/div/main-content/div/norma-
                cadastro/div/form/div[7]/datapicker/form/div[1]/input'));
        fimVigencia.sendKeys('abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvxz123456789');
        element(by.buttonText('Salvar')).click();
        expect(fimVigencia.getAttribute('ng-reflect-
                                        model')).toBe('123456789');
 });
```

**Error**: Expected null to be '1234567'.

Comment: You should describe your problem clearly and past original HTML code related to attribute ng-reflect-model. And also tell what happened after click button.

Comment: @SureshSalloju I'm sorry, I don't know how to write English very well that's why I have some dificult to express myself.

Comment: @alecxe What you mean? It's the last attribute.